# Download HTML/Page as PDF in Phonegap App

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, jspdf, html2pdf

I'm currently writing a mobile app via Phonegap with HTML/CSS/JS. I'd simply like to save the contents of the current page as a PDF file.

I've tried jsPDF and html2PDF, but to no avail. Upon testing in my Chrome browser, every result just leaves a clickable button that does nothing.

Since I'm new to JavaScript, correct me if I'm wrong - to test the code, I simply need to open up the HTML file into my browser and the code should function? I've been testing the following code I found [on the web](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/html-to-pdf-in-javascript/), but I'm left with a blank, clickable button when testing in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>HTML to PDF Eample</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      function generatePDF() {
        // Choose the element that our invoice is rendered in.
        const element = document.getElementById("invoice");
        // Choose the element and save the PDF for our user.
        html2pdf()
          .from(element)
          .save();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="generatePDF()">Download as PDF</button>
    <div id="invoice">
      <h1>Our Invoice</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Every time I test the code in my browser or mobile via Phonegap, I'm left with a clickable button that does nothing. I believe I set everything up correctly. I downloaded the html2pdf github repo and put the JS files into my project's JS folder. But I'm still not sure why my button won't work.

Any ideas? Any and all contributions would be deeply appreciated. Additionally, if there's another way to save a page/HTML to pdf that'd be perfect, too.

Edit: Errors in the console:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add this **Meta**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src *;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-eval' *"> 

<span>None</span>
<div id="invoice">
    <span> Invoice Info </span>
    <span> 2020-07-20 </span>
    <span> $$$  </span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</button>
```

and add this script **jspdf.min.js** and  **dom-to-image.min.js**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
```

use this fucntion to convert into **PDF**

```
 function downloadPDF(){
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('invoice'))
        .then(function (blob) {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height()]);

            pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height());
            pdf.save("test.pdf");

            that.options.api.optionsChanged();
        });

        }
```

Comment: It works in JSFiddle, but I can't get it to work in the browser. I've tried placing the script basically everywhere on the HTML document but to no avail.

Comment: try to use phonegap serve and check if it's work in browser

Comment: still not working on the phonegap server :( one iteration of the code gave a couple of errors in the console. I added them to the original post above. Not sure what they mean.

Comment: this warning msg Related to Meta Tag try delete it and check if it's working in browser , and try to export apk and check in your phone if it's working with this tag Meta